# How to get hdfs configuration info by using libhdfs.so

Tags: java, c, hadoop, configuration, hdfs

As title, in JAVA API, there are several methods in org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration to get details about what we have configure in hdfs configurion files. Such as hdfs-site.xml, core-site.xml. But I want to get this by using C API, libhdfs.so. could any body help me ?

Answer (score 1):

Example program of libhdfs, C++ library to handle HDFS (Hadoop Distributed File System)use the following link

[libhdfs](https://github.com/kzk/libhdfs-example/blob/master/README.md)